# HP Imaging drivers for Windows 2008 Server

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2

We've got old HP Deskjet F2180 and have it connected to win server 2008 R2 64-bit. Printing works fine, but I can't get scanner working. I've done it once, installing some "universal" driver package obtained from HP.com. Windows XP and Vista drivers (drivers only packages) writes something about missing files and wrong INF file. HP "Full" setup simply crashes without any messages, though I don't want it on server. If anyone can provide me a hint, how to install XP or Vista drivers on server 2008, or any advice about compatible driver packages (for scanners, or maybe any konica compatible products) I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Did you try the W7 64bit full Feature software installer (245mb) from this page?...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3177562#N193

Comment: It doesn't work due to "incompatible operating system" or just crash depending on compatibility settings. AFAIK, Vista drivers are more preferrable for 2008 server, but them don't work neither.

Comment: Can you unpack the Vista drivers and modify the inf file?